# AWS volume larger than specified

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created an AWS instance with an attached volume of size 500 GB.  Everything looks good in AWS console which shows the volume to be 500 GB (it is /dev/xvdf).  When I ssh into the instance and look at the drive I see the drive is actually 540 GB instead of 500 GB.  Why is this, where did this extra 40 GB come from?

fdisk output:

```
Disk /dev/xvdf: 536.9 GB, 536870912000 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 65270 cylinders, total 1048576000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

df -h (uses 1024):

```
/dev/xvdf       493G  110G  358G  24% /data0
```

df -H (uses 1000):

```
/dev/xvdf       529G  118G  384G  24% /data0
```

Comment: This isn't really a programming question and probably belongs on another site. For starters, you should include the output from `df -H` in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your volume size is correct.

536,870,912,000 ÷ 1,024 ÷ 1,024 ÷ 1,024 = 500 GiB.

1 GiB ("gibibyte," or giga-binary byte) is 2<sup>30</sup> bytes.  EBS volume sizes are in GiB.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong but "/dev/xvdf" Shows that AWS is using some form of Xen
be that XenServer or some other flavor.

What happens is:
Xen calculates how much space is actually needed so that after you format the volume to "ext4" or any other FS you will have 500GB or as close to it as possible.

Anyways this is IME.